# Настройка docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

```
ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localunixsocket - is it running?

If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.
```

Подскажите что означает  данная ошибка и как ее поправить?

Comment: два варианта - либо докер-демон не запущен (проверка - `ps aux | grep docker`), либо попробуйте запустить команду от имени администратора.

Comment: 2 вариант, спасибо

Comment: Оф документация рекомендует запускать от имени обычного пользователя, для этого надо добавить его в группу  `sudo gpasswd -a $USER docker` и ребутнуться.

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от того из какой среды вы запускаете docker.

1. Если вы запускаете его из linux системы, то скорее всего Docker demon по какой-то причине не запустился или установлен не корректно. Как уже сказали выше проверьте запущен ли соответствующий процесс: ps aux | grep docker
2. Если вы запускаете Docker на Windows или Mac OS, например с виртуальной машины через docker toolbox, то у вас могут быть проблемы с сетевыми мостом виртуальной машины из-за чего docker cli не может подключиться к демону.